# Docker building image from command line

Tags: docker, docker-build

I try to run following commands:

```
$ docker build - <<EOF
FROM mysql:8
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
COPY ./data.sql /docker/entrypoint-initdb.d/
EOF
```

but I always get this error:

```
failed to compute cache key: "/data.sql" not found: not found
```

The data.sql is where I run the command from, so I don't understand why it does not find the data.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a Dockerfile like this, you implicitly do not pass the build context. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--):

> ```
> docker build - < Dockerfile
> ```
>
> This will read a Dockerfile from STDIN without context. Due to the lack of a context, no contents of any local directory will be sent to the Docker daemon. Since there is no context, a Dockerfile ADD only works if it refers to a remote URL.

Therefore, there is no context to copy the data.sql file from. The input when you run `docker build -` is either a Dockerfile or a compressed tar of the context:

> ```
> docker build - < context.tar.gz
> ```
>
> This will build an image for a compressed context read from STDIN. Supported formats are: bzip2, gzip and xz.

Comment: I replaced COPY keyword to ADD but I still get same issue:
```
$ docker build -<<EOF
FROM mysql:8
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
ADD ./data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EOF
```

Comment: @thomas that's not a remote URL. You're still trying to copy a file from an empty context.